# How to search string for multiple values?

Tags: javascript

This code works:

```
if ((filenameTmp == "thunderstorm") || 
   (filenameTmp == "fog") || 
   (filenameTmp == "hail") ||
   (filenameTmp == "heavy_snow") ||
   (filenameTmp == "rain") ||
   (filenameTmp == "sleet") ||
   (filenameTmp == "snow"))
{ document.getElementById("twilightBG").style.display = "none"; }
```

However I would like to shorten it, I thought this would work but it doesn't.

```
if(filenameTmp.indexOf ("thunderstorm", "fog", "hail", "heavy_snow", "haze", "sleet", "snow")> -1)
{ document.getElementById("twilightBG").style.display = "none"; }
```

It does work if I only have a single search like this:

```
if(filenameTmp.indexOf ("haze")> -1)
{ document.getElementById("twilightBG").style.display = "none"; }
```

How can I do it searching for multiple instances? Or is there a better way? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Jquery as well, or only pure javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three options for you:

1. A map object
2. An array lookup
3. `switch`

Details:

1. You can use a lookup map object:

   ```
   // In a common declarations area
   var weather = {
       "thunderstorm": true,
       "fog": true,
       "hail": true,
       "heavy_snow": true,
       "rain": true,
       "sleet": true,
       "snow": true
   };

   // Where you want the check
   if (weather[filenameTmp]) {
       document.getElementById("twilightBG").style.display = "none";
   }
   ```

   Note that you *can* do that inline if you like:

   ```
   if ({ "thunderstorm": true, "fog": true, "hail": true, "heavy_snow": true, "rain": true, "sleet": true, "snow": true }[filenameTmp]) {
       document.getElementById("twilightBG").style.display = "none";
   }
   ```

   Note that if `filenameTmp` has the value `"toString"`, `"valueOf"`, or similar, you'll get false-positives from that. If you're using a true ES5-enabled engine, you can get *pure* maps (objects that don't have `toString` and such) by using a builder function:

   ```
   function pureMap(props) {
       var o = Object.create(null);
       var key;
       if (props) {
           for (key in props) {
               o[key] = props[key];
           }
       }
       return o;
   }
   ```

   Then:

   ```
   // In a common declarations area
   var weather = pureMap({
       "thunderstorm": true,
       "fog": true,
       "hail": true,
       "heavy_snow": true,
       "rain": true,
       "sleet": true,
       "snow": true
   });

   // Where you want the check
   if (weather[filenameTmp]) {
       document.getElementById("twilightBG").style.display = "none";
   }
   ```
2. Or you could use an array, but the search is linear whereas browsers can optimize the map lookup above:

   ```
   // In a common declarations area
   var weather = [
       "thunderstorm",
       "fog",
       "hail",
       "heavy_snow",
       "rain",
       "sleet",
       "snow"
   ];

   // Where you want the check
   if (weather.indexOf(filenameTmp) !== -1) {
       document.getElementById("twilightBG").style.display = "none";
   }
   ```

   And again, that *can* be inline:

   ```
   if ([ "thunderstorm", "fog", "hail", "heavy_snow", "rain", "sleet", "snow" ].indexOf(filenameTmp) !== -1) {
       document.getElementById("twilightBG").style.display = "none";
   }
   ```
3. There's also the `switch` option:

   ```
   switch (filenameTmp) {
       case "thunderstorm":
       case "fog":
       case "hail":
       case "heavy_snow":
       case "rain":
       case "sleet":
       case "snow":
           document.getElementById("twilightBG").style.display = "none";
           break;
   }
   ```

Comment: all right, but **if (weather[filenameTmp])** is not the same of **IndexOf > -1**

Answer (score 4):

You can use the match() method together with a regex

`var.match(^(?:apple|pear|whatever)$/)`

Comment: +1, but you'll want anchors on that, and if you're not using the resulting match array it's better to use `test`: `if (/^(?:thunderstorm|fog|hail|heavy_snow|rain|sleet|snow)$/.test(filenameTmp)) { /*...*/ }`

Comment: won't your regex check for a string that IS "thunderstorm", "fog" etc.? If I understood it correctly the question asks to check if the string contains those words. (btw feel free to improve the answer if you wish so!)

Comment: The OP's code in the question under "This code works:" is checking that the string *is* "thunderstorm," etc., not that it contains it.

Comment: My bad, reading the questions from mobile is really a pain. (Fixing the regex right now)

Answer (score 3):

You may use the array approach like this:

```
if (["thunderstorm", "fog", "hail", "heavy_snow", "haze", "sleet", "snow"].indexOf(filenameTmp) >= 0) {
```

Comment: This won't work in older browsers (ie < 8 to name one)

Comment: Thanks, I did try an array but I got the syntax wrong, this works perfect for my needs (iPhone only). This is the method I'm now using.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (["thunderstorm", "fog", "hail", "heavy_snow", "haze", "sleet", "snow"].indexOf(filenameTmp) !== -1) {
document.getElementById("twilightBG").style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The check would be cleaner if the **contains** method were added to **Array.prototype** directly:

```
Array.prototype.contains = function(obj) { return this.indexOf(obj) > -1; };
```

This allows the check to be:

```
if (['thunderstorm', 'fog', 'hail', 'heavy_snow', 'rain', 'sleet', 'snow'].contains(filenameTmp)) {
document.getElementById("twilightBG").style.display = "none";
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Use Array and loop through every entry . this is most efficient way .By this it ll not loop thru all entry once it encounter any one.

```
function containsAny(str, substrings) {
    for (var i = 0; i != substrings.length; i++) {
        var substring = substrings[i];
        if (str == substring) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

var result = containsAny(filenameTmp, ["thunderstrom", "rain"]); // add values you want
if (result) {
    document.getElementById("twilightBG").style.display = "none";
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

For a bleeding edge solution use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). Keep in mind it's not currently supported on Opera and Safari:

```
var weather = new Set();

weather.add("thunderstorm");
weather.add("fog");
weather.add("hail");
weather.add("heavy_snow");
weather.add("rain");
weather.add("sleet");
weather.add("snow");

if (weather.has(filenameTmp)) {
    document.getElementById("twilightBG").style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regx:

```
if (filenameTmp.match(/^(thunderstorm|fog|hail|heavy_snow|rain|sleet|snow)$/)) {
    document.getElementById("twilightBG").style.display = "none";
    }
```

or array of js 5:

```
if (['thunderstorm', 'fog', 'hail', 'heavy_snow','rain','sleet','snow'].indexOf(filenameTmp) >= 0) {
document.getElementById("twilightBG").style.display = "none";
}
```

or inArray method of Jquery:

```
if ($.inArray(filenameTmp, ['thunderstorm', 'fog', 'hail', 'heavy_snow','rain','sleet','snow']) >= 0) {
document.getElementById("twilightBG").style.display = "none";
}
```